# How to get Same height of box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how can I get responsive same height of product box, when I insert a different size of an image for my product from admin panel it shows the different height of the boxes, [image: Issue]

My CSS

```
/* Products Styles  */


.flex-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

#hot h2 {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 36px;
color: #4993e4;
font-weight: 100;
text-align: center;

}

#content {
padding-left:25px;

}

.single {
width:290px;
margin: auto;
}


}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.single {

width:100;
margin: auto;
}

}

#content .product {
background:#fff;
border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#content .product .text p.price {
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
font-weight:300;

}

#content .product .text .buttons {
clear:both;
text-align:center;
}

#content .product .text h3 {
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;

}

#content .product .text h3 a {

color:rgb(85, 85, 85);
}

#content .product .text {
padding:10px 10px 0px;
}

#content .product .text .buttons .btn {
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could upload your html along with the css!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/programlover/qLd0637w/

Comment: This link isnt helpful, as the issue you are facing is not highlighted in that source code.

Comment: actually i wrote all code in php here is php file         https://jsfiddle.net/programlover/a83jof6q/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Add min-width and min-height for container.**

Answer (score 0):

Try with min-width

```
 @media (min-width:1025px) { 
    .global-container {
        margin-top: 0;
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

For more please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323818/css-define-media-query-within-one-class)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this, since you've used `flexbox` in your code I came up with this example.

```css
.box {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box .column {
  flex: 1;
  background: #aaa;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a little tricky one.

put image as background of an element and make it cover the whole element :

```css
.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.box {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    width: 50%;
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    width: 33%;
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.box>.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.box>.content>.image {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px; // this should be responsive :
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1011/9246/products/351_78763716-fe86-4fa6-a97a-9f3b92d32120_large.jpg?v=1543489483')"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://www.marimekko.com/media/catalog/product/cache/4/small_image/738x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/0/4/046563-345_10_1541563567.jpg')"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

this approach automatically keeps the aspect ratio of the image. and the size of image doesn't matter here. you just need to handle the responsive `height` style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use make your design unbreakable with custom height product box.

```css
.flexlist {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexlist-item {
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 15px);
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  background: #efefef;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flexlist">
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>

  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is
    simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
  <li class="flexlist-item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is
    simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: still i cant get..can you tell me how can i get all the image size same which is fit in div

Comment: In my solution you can set each product box of row not image of product box  with  equal height. If you need to set equal height of all images we can set it but in your design that is not issue of images .Your design  issue is all  product boxes height is even odd so, we can make  equal height of all product box with flex box.